# Auroville Visa Run (without flying)

Tags: visas, india

What options do I have to exit & re-enter India without flying?

I'm currently in Auroville, India. I have a 1-year visa, but my visa requires that I leave and re-enter the country every 6 months.

Auroville is in South East India in Tamil Nadu. Sri Lanka is the closest country, but I can't figure out how to get there without flying. I've read that there used to be a ferry, but I can't find out how to take it.

Other land-border countries include Pakistan, Bangladesh, Nepal, China, Bhutan, and Burma. Due to the nationalist government currently in India, I'm concerned about going to Pakistan or Bangladesh -- I've heard it can cause issues on re-entry to India. Nepal is definitely an option, but it's a very long train ride away. I think Bhutan and China are logistics nightmares, and I've never heard of someone doing a visa run to Burma.

Are there any ways to get to Sri Lanka from Tamil Nadu without flying? Otherwise, what's the best option to do a Visa Run from Auroville?

Comment: Maldives would be the obvious option, but there doesn't seem to be a passenger ferry between the two at the moment, although there's regular cargo service between Kochi and Male.  It's a short flight though.

Comment: What is your nationality? Is it an islamic country? If not, you are unlikely to face problems when getting from Bangladesh into India (even though it might take time). Border formalities will definitely be faster to and from Nepal. Pakistan, China, Bhutan and Myanmar are out of question for various reasons. And of coure make sure your Indian visa allows reentry!

Comment: What's the reason for not wanting to fly?

Comment: Sri Lanka: There is no ferry; instead, take a train to Rameswaram and then a boat to Talaimannar, which is time-consuming and prone to delays.
Nepal: A visa run is possible; cross the border at Sonauli and use trains/buses to Kathmandu.
Bangladesh: Avoid owing to the political environment and border concerns.
Consider traveling from Tamil Nadu to a neighboring nation while adhering to visa requirements, such as a passport, return ticket, and proof of finances. safe travel!

Comment: Related: [To travel 30 km from India to Sri Lanka, do I really have to take a 1500 km, 20 hour detour?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/68320/)

Comment: I'm sure there's a good reason but why *not* fly?